# Displaying a Table of Database Data in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Made solution change: I am trying to display a html table of data.. In my controller I  start an object as null and then pass the object as a reference to update the object based on the info in the DB like so "user control named(Indexcontrol.ascx)":

```
        List<dataob> data = null;
        dataManager target = new dataManager();
        //pass the parameter to a stored procedure and update it
        target.LoadFromDatabase(ref data);
        this.ViewData.Model =data;
        return View("Index");
```

I am trying to see how to display a table once the information is in the data object using a similar route all this is in the user control

```
 <tbody >

<% foreach (businesslayer.dataob m in  ViewData.Model) 
{ %>
<tr>
 <td><%= m.ID%></td>
 <td><%= m.Date %></td>
 <td><%= m.Description %></td>
 </tr>
 <% } %>


</tbody>
```

I figured out the problem....since I had the table attribute set to runat=server thats what gave me the error..don't know why but it did

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are avoiding the ViewData.Model.  There is no reason, that I can see in this case, why:

```
 ViewData["data"] = data;
```

is preferrable to

```
 ViewData.Model = data;
```

If you used a strongly typed View page, you could then avoid the need to cast the Model as well.  Then you could simply do:

```
 <% foreach (dataob m in ViewData.Model) { %>
    <tr> 
        <td><%= m.Id %></td>
        <td><%= m.user %></td>
        <td><%= m.Date %></td>
    </tr>
 <% } %>
```

Comment: This is how I'd do it myself, without the seemingly irrational fear of using ViewData.Model

Comment: The "fear" comes from the last sentence of his question. He needs to use a strongly typed model.

Comment: I did that and it works but now I am trying to integrate it within a user control and it will not work

Comment: Is your user control strongly typed as well?

Comment: yes it is strongly typed..you mean this right in code behind? public partial class Datacontrol : System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<List<dataob>>

Comment: But you aren't passing the list to the user control, only one item from the list.  You want it to be ViewUserControl<dataob>, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<% foreach (dataob m in (IEnumerable<dataob>) ViewData["data"]) { %>
```

Comment: that  <dataob> shows a syntax error saying that type or namespace name 'dataob' can not be found. but I imported the same class that I imported in the controller?

Comment: You may need to import the namespace of dataobj in your web.config? I can only guess without seeing the whole project.

Comment: use <%@ Import Namespace="your-dataob-namespace" %> in the view

Comment: Note: I don't think this is required if you use a strongly-typed view as I suggest in my answer.